# Does PEP 476 affect non-TLS connections?

Tags: python, https, urllib, pep

When making a request with `urllib`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
f = urlopen('http://example.com/foo')
```

I observed: `urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28052583/21115) led me to [PEP 476](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/), and I was able to resolve the issue using:

```
f = urlopen('http://example.com/foo', context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
```

---

My question is:

Why does this this work, given that my request uses `http://` and **not** `https://`?